# What's the fastest way to create a C-compatible unbounded string in Ada?

Tags: interface, ada, c-strings

I'm creating an Ada program for Windows that needs to be able to pass strings to some functions written in C. Until now I have been manipulating the strings in Ada using the `Unbounded_String` type, and then converting the data to an `Interfaces.C.char_array` before passing it to the C functions.

This works fine, only performance is a bit of an issue on slower, older computers. The C function is sometimes called repeatedly on a slightly modified version of a string, and requires the `Unbounded_String` to be converted to a similar `char_array` every time. The strings aren't modified by the C functions, so the only ever have to be converted to `char_array`.

I have thought of storing the strings in `char_array`, and converting from an Ada type each time the string is manipulated. The data is passed to C more often than it is changed, so it would improve performance. The problem with this approach is that often the length of the string will change, sometimes by a lot, and there is no way of knowing the maximum length beforehand.

The ideal solution would be to have something similar to an `Unbounded_String` only storing the string as a `char_array`. By this I mean something that is dynamically sized, allocating a new array when the old one isn't big enough and it should allow Ada `Characters`/`Strings` to be inserted (and also removed) into the array, converting only those characters to C `chars`.

Is there any (relatively) easy, fast way of doing this without having to implement it myself? Or is there any other quick way of manipulating C-compatible strings in Ada? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention how many objects you expect to have of your type, but I will assume that we are not talking about so many that you will be anywhere near exhausting your available address space.

Just encapsulate a sufficiently large `char_array` (say 10 times the largest expected size) in a private record, and create the needed operations to manipulate it.

If you're very unlucky, you may need to tell your compiler/run-time environment that you need an unusually large stack, but save that worry for when you actually experience it.